# get first element from list in dictionary c#

Tags: c#, dictionary

I use the following structure

```
Dictionary<string, List<object>>
```

I want to get the first element from list for entered certain key.

thank you

Comment: 1. What have you tried, and what happened? 2. Do you have any guarantee that the key provided actually exists in the dictionary?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
if (myDictionary.ContainsKey("myKey"))
   var myItem = myDictionary["myKey"].FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: the other answers also work but this one won't throw an exception if the key or value are missing.  that may or may not be what you want...

Comment: @Robert - i try to leave exceptions for the exceptional cases.

Comment: sure, i just wanted to call this out so OP can consciously decide whether or not a missing key or value is exceptional in his case

Answer (score 1):

```
object item = dictionary[key].First();
```

or you could use `FirstOrDefault` if you can't be certain the list contains any items.

Or if you can't be certain the key exists:

```
object item = dictionary.ContainsKey(key) ? dictionary[key].FirstOrDefault() : null;
if(item != null) { ... }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var myValue = myDict[myKey][0];
```

This doesn't work for you?

Answer (score 0):

```
Dictionary<string, List<object>> item = new Dictionary<string, List<object>>();
string key="this is the key";
object firstItem = item[key][0];
```

This code presumes the key exists and that theres at least 1 item in the collection